# Почему не устанавливается grpc?

Tags: node.js, npm

При установке Node модулей(npm install) столкнулся со следующей ошибкой.

[image: npm install]

Скажите пожалуйста с чем она может быть связанна ?

Почему возникает ошибка 403 ?

[(Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz)]

Как можно решить проблему ?

Или где можно найти документацию для решения проблемы. ?

С Уважением Сергей

Comment: Судя по [issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/121) надо отключить антивирус.

Comment: не из за антивируса.

1: Убрал из package.json  firebase
2: npm instal (установка прошла успешно)

added 1152 packages from 660 contributors and audited 13386 packages in 160.221s
found 3 vulnerabilities (2 low, 1 critical)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

3: npm audit fix

Всё океюшки

Comment: Ну так проблема в нем и заключалась, если этот пакет нужен, то судя по ответам помогает отключение антивирусника (как вариант) или установка последней версии без grpc в зависимостях. Если он не нужен, то смысла в вопросе нет.

Comment: Смысл есть совсем для новичков( отключение антивируса мне не помогло например) и в интернете очень смутно на эту тему пишут... Теперь будет два простых варианта проверить.

1. Отключить антивирус
2. Посмотреть зависимости в package.json